# Insert column in org-mode moves the content

Tags: org-mode, org-table, column

I am trying to insert a column in a table in org-mode and I get the content moved.
For example, I have this table:

```
| Name   | Age |
|--------+-----|
| Tarzan |  40 |
| Jane   |  39 |
```

Now I want to insert a column between Name and Age.
So I add a pipe (`|`) just after Name:

```
| Name  | | Age |
|--------+-----|
| Tarzan |  40 |
| Jane   |  39 |
```

And the press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
I get this:

```
| Name   |    | Age |
|--------+----+-----|
| Tarzan | 40 |     |
| Jane   | 39 |     |
```

While what I would expect is:

```
| Name   |    | Age |
|--------+----+-----|
| Tarzan |    |  40 |
| Jane   |    |  39 |
```

It seems kind of simple to fix manually for that table, but... I haven't told you all the story.
In the real table I have Boy, Cheeta, Cheeta's family, the herd of elephants, lions, tigers, crocodiles, etc... and all the *psychological relationships* between them...

Is there a way to avoid that column content move?

Answer (score 7):

Just positioning at the column:

```
       cursor here
          |
          V
| Name   |■Age |
|--------+-----|
| Tarzan |  40 |
| Jane   |  39 |
```

and using <kbd>M-S-right</kbd> `(org-table-insert-column)` makes it:

```
| Name   |   | Age |
|--------+---+-----|
| Tarzan |   |  40 |
| Jane   |   |  39 |
```

From the org-mode manual:

```
M-S-<right>     (org-table-insert-column)
Insert a new column to the left of the cursor position.
```